# Simple Tictactoe game in Typescript

Tags: tic-tac-toe, typescript, angular-2+

I'm mostly wondering if I can simplify the code. I've been told that it's
needlessly complicated.

HTML:

```
<div class="board">
  <div id="tl" class="tldarkmode" (click)="fill(1)">{{ valtl }}</div>
  <div id="t" class="tdarkmode" (click)="fill(2)">{{ valt }}</div>
  <div id="tr" class="trdarkmode" (click)="fill(3)">{{ valtr }}</div>
  <div id="cl" class="cldarkmode" (click)="fill(4)">{{ valcl }}</div>
  <div id="c" class="cdarkmode" (click)="fill(5)">{{ valc }}</div>
  <div id="cr" class="crdarkmode" (click)="fill(6)">{{ valcr }}</div>
  <div id="bl" class="bldarkmode" (click)="fill(7)">{{ valbl }}</div>
  <div id="b" class="bdarkmode" (click)="fill(8)">{{ valb }}</div>
  <div id="br" class="brdarkmode" (click)="fill(9)">{{ valbr }}</div>
</div>
<div id="turnmsg">
  {{ msg }}
</div>

<input
  class="newgamebutton"
  type="button"
  value="New Game"
  (click)="newgame()"
  title="Start a new game"
/>
```

Typescript:

```
export class GameComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit() {}

  public turn: number = 1;
  public count: number = 0;
  public msg: string = "";
  public buttonvalue = "";
  public winflag: number = -1;

  public valtl: string = "";
  public valt: string = "";
  public valtr: string = "";
  public valcl: string = "";
  public valc: string = "";
  public valcr: string = "";
  public valbl: string = "";
  public valb: string = "";
  public valbr: string = "";

  fill(cell: number) {
    if (cell == 1) {
      if (this.turn == 1) {
        if (this.winflag == -1) {
          if (this.valtl == "") {
            this.valtl = "X";
            this.turn = this.turn + 1;
            this.msg = "Player O's turn";
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (this.winflag == -1) {
          if (this.valtl == "") {
            this.valtl = "O";
            this.turn = this.turn - 1;
            this.msg = "Player X's turn";
          }
        }
      }
      if (this.winflag == -1) {
        this.count = this.count + 1;
      }
      this.checkwin();
    }
    if (cell == 2) {
      if (this.turn == 1) {
        if (this.winflag == -1) {
          if (this.valt == "") {
            this.valt = "X";
            this.turn = this.turn + 1;
            this.msg = "Player O's turn";
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (this.winflag == -1) {
          if (this.valt == "") {
            this.valt = "O";
            this.turn = this.turn - 1;
            this.msg = "Player X's turn";
          }
        }
      }
      if (this.winflag == -1) {
        this.count = this.count + 1;
      }
      this.checkwin();
    }
    if (cell == 3) {
      if (this.turn == 1) {
        if (this.winflag == -1) {
          if (this.valtr == "") {
            this.valtr = "X";
            this.turn = this.turn + 1;
            this.msg = "Player O's turn";
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (this.winflag == -1) {
          if (this.valtr == "") {
            this.valtr = "O";
            this.turn = this.turn - 1;
            this.msg = "Player X's turn";
          }
        }
      }
      if (this.winflag == -1) {
        this.count = this.count + 1;
      }
      this.checkwin();
    }
    if (cell == 4) {
      if (this.turn == 1) {
        if (this.winflag == -1) {
          if (this.valcl == "") {
            this.valcl = "X";
            this.turn = this.turn + 1;
            this.msg = "Player O's turn";
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (this.winflag == -1) {
          if (this.valcl == "") {
            this.valcl = "O";
            this.turn = this.turn - 1;
            this.msg = "Player X's turn";
          }
        }
      }
      if (this.winflag == -1) {
        this.count = this.count + 1;
      }
      this.checkwin();
    }
    if (cell == 5) {
      if (this.turn == 1) {
        if (this.winflag == -1) {
          if (this.valc == "") {
            this.valc = "X";
            this.turn = this.turn + 1;
            this.msg = "Player O's turn";
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (this.winflag == -1) {
          if (this.valc == "") {
            this.valc = "O";
            this.turn = this.turn - 1;
            this.msg = "Player X's turn";
          }
        }
      }
      if (this.winflag == -1) {
        this.count = this.count + 1;
      }
      this.checkwin();
    }
    if (cell == 6) {
      if (this.turn == 1) {
        if (this.winflag == -1) {
          if (this.valcr == "") {
            this.valcr = "X";
            this.turn = this.turn + 1;
            this.msg = "Player O's turn";
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (this.winflag == -1) {
          if (this.valcr == "") {
            this.valcr = "O";
            this.turn = this.turn - 1;
            this.msg = "Player X's turn";
          }
        }
      }
      if (this.winflag == -1) {
        this.count = this.count + 1;
      }
      this.checkwin();
    }
    if (cell == 7) {
      if (this.turn == 1) {
        if (this.winflag == -1) {
          if (this.valbl == "") {
            this.valbl = "X";
            this.turn = this.turn + 1;
            this.msg = "Player O's turn";
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (this.winflag == -1) {
          if (this.valbl == "") {
            this.valbl = "O";
            this.turn = this.turn - 1;
            this.msg = "Player X's turn";
          }
        }
      }
      if (this.winflag == -1) {
        this.count = this.count + 1;
      }
      this.checkwin();
    }
    if (cell == 8) {
      if (this.turn == 1) {
        if (this.winflag == -1) {
          if (this.valb == "") {
            this.valb = "X";
            this.turn = this.turn + 1;
            this.msg = "Player O's turn";
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (this.winflag == -1) {
          if (this.valb == "") {
            this.valb = "O";
            this.turn = this.turn - 1;
            this.msg = "Player X's turn";
          }
        }
      }
      if (this.winflag == -1) {
        this.count = this.count + 1;
      }
      this.checkwin();
    }
    if (cell == 9) {
      if (this.turn == 1) {
        if (this.winflag == -1) {
          if (this.valbr == "") {
            this.valbr = "X";
            this.turn = this.turn + 1;
            this.msg = "Player O's turn";
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (this.winflag == -1) {
          if (this.valbr == "") {
            this.valbr = "O";
            this.turn = this.turn - 1;
            this.msg = "Player X's turn";
          }
        }
      }
      if (this.winflag == -1) {
        this.count = this.count + 1;
      }
      this.checkwin();
    }
  }

  checkwin() {
    if (
      (this.valtl == "X" && this.valt == "X" && this.valtr == "X") ||
      (this.valcl == "X" && this.valc == "X" && this.valcr == "X") ||
      (this.valbl == "X" && this.valb == "X" && this.valbr == "X") ||
      (this.valtl == "X" && this.valcl == "X" && this.valbl == "X") ||
      (this.valt == "X" && this.valc == "X" && this.valb == "X") ||
      (this.valtr == "X" && this.valcr == "X" && this.valbr == "X") ||
      (this.valtl == "X" && this.valc == "X" && this.valbr == "X") ||
      (this.valtr == "X" && this.valc == "X" && this.valbl == "X")
    ) {
      this.msg = "Player X wins";
      this.winflag = 1;
    } else if (this.count == 9) {
      //alert("It's a draw"!);
      this.msg = "It's a Draw";
      this.winflag = 0;
    } else if (
      (this.valtl == "O" && this.valt == "O" && this.valtr == "O") ||
      (this.valcl == "O" && this.valc == "O" && this.valcr == "O") ||
      (this.valbl == "O" && this.valb == "O" && this.valbr == "O") ||
      (this.valtl == "O" && this.valcl == "O" && this.valbl == "O") ||
      (this.valt == "O" && this.valc == "O" && this.valb == "O") ||
      (this.valtr == "O" && this.valcr == "O" && this.valbr == "O") ||
      (this.valtl == "O" && this.valc == "O" && this.valbr == "O") ||
      (this.valtr == "O" && this.valc == "O" && this.valbl == "O")
    ) {
      this.msg = "Player O wins";
      this.winflag = 2;
    }
  }

  newgame() {
    this.turn = 1;
    this.msg = "";
    this.count = 0;
    this.valtl = "";
    this.valt = "";
    this.valtr = "";
    this.valcl = "";
    this.valc = "";
    this.valcr = "";
    this.valbl = "";
    this.valb = "";
    this.valbr = "";
    this.winflag = -1;
  }
}
```